# Как узнать с какими параметрами был создан контейнер (docker run)?

Tags: docker

Командой

```
docker ps
```

выводится список контейнеров.
Один из контейнеров был запущен 3 года назад и висит.
Можно ли как то узнать с какими параметрами он был создан (docker run)?

Comment: `docker inspect <container name/id>` возможно покажет достаточную информацию

Comment: А можно как то конвертировать docker-compose сервис в команду docker run?

Comment: Вопрос подняли спустя ещё 3 года, и мне теперь жутко интересно, работает ли этот контейнер до сих пор)

Answer (score 0):

docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock assaflavie/runlike YOUR-CONTAINER-NAME

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]